# Cannot retrieve database info in blade view

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am not able to pass database info to my blade file. I want to display all database entries on one page. What am I doing wrong?

**diary.blade.php**

```
 @foreach($posts as $post)
     <Tr>
         <th>{{ $post->id }}</th>
         <th>{{ $post->body }}</th>
     </Tr>
 @endforeach
```

---

**web.php**

```
Route::get('diary', 'DiaryController@index')->name('diary');
```

---

**DiaryController.php**

```
 public function index()
 {
     $posts = DB::table('entries')->get();
     return view ('user.diary')->with('diary', $posts);
 }
```

Comment: You called your array `diary`, not `posts`.

Comment: @tkausl Holy shit wow :\ thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable name you are passing is incorrect, instead of

`return view ('user.diary')->with('diary', $posts);`

you should do

`return view ('user.diary')->with('posts', $posts);`

Here are some alternate ways you can pass data to your view:-

```
return view('user.diary', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

OR

```
return view ('user.diary')->with('posts', $posts);
```

OR

```
return view('user.diary', compact('posts'));
```

Hopefully, this helps with your question.

Comment: Any pros/cons to using the alternative methods you used? Or is it just personal preference?

Comment: There's no difference, its just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
return view ('user.diary')->with('posts', $posts);
```